An example of an infinite group $G$ such that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cong$ $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$.
Since the left multiplication by a nontrivial $a\in G$ is not a homomorphism, the automorphism group of a nontrivial group $G$ is always a proper subgroup of the symmetric group of (the underlying set of) $G$. Accordingly, if $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is finite (which is certainly the case if $G$ itself is finite), then the condition $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cong$ $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ becomes $\operatorname{Aut}(G)=$ $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$, and hence $G$ must be the trivial group.
In order to convince myself that the finiteness assumption is truly necessary for the triviality of $G$ (in the assumption $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cong$ $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$), I'm looking for an example of an infinite group $G$ such that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cong\operatorname{Sym}(G)$. For further reference about the finite (hence $G$ trivial) case, see e.g. here.
Edit. This post argues that "[...] It seems like it is in fact impossible to have these two isomorphic as a groups [...]", and narrows the search to cases where at least the two cardinals are equal. And the answer therein recalls @user3257842's comment here below.

Since the identity must be preserved by an automorphism, this is not possible.

How do you define Sym(G)?

@ahulpke Your argument shows that the natural inclusion $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ is never surjective, but that doesn't imply that these groups aren't isomorphic. Infinite groups may have proper subgroups that are isomorphic to the whole group.

If $G$ is infinite, then there are proper subgroups of Sym$(G)$ (for example, the stabilizer of the identity) isomorphic to the whole symmetric group.

Consider the group $G$ of infinite sequences of integers of which all but a finite number of the elements of a sequence are $0$, with composition being element-wise addition of said sequences. I think it's called the infinite direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}$.  We know $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is included naturally in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$, but we can also make a (not exactly natural) inclusion of $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, as $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ contains all bijections of $\mathbb{N}$, and $G$ is countable. Unfortunately I've not been able to prove or disprove more.

I assume you mean $\mathrm{Sym}(UG)$ where $UG$ is the underlying set of $G$.

Does $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ mean anything different, @MartinBrandenburg? I'm curious.

The symmetric group is not defined for groups.

Every time I have seen the symmetric group mentioned over the underlying set of an infinite group $G$, $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ has been used.  I think Robinson uses it for instance, @MartinBrandenburg.

I seem to remember that if $X$ is an infinite set, then the automorphism group of $\operatorname{FSym}(X)$, the group of finitary permutations of $X$, is $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$, which would answer the question, since $X$ and $\operatorname{FSym}(X)$ have the same cardinality. I won’t post this as an answer until I confirm my memory by finding a reference or proof, but if anybody else does so first, then they’re welcome to post an answer before me.

Let $X$ be an infinite set, and let $G=\operatorname{FSym}(X)$, the group of finitary permutations of $X$ (i.e., permutations that fix all but finitely many elements of $X$).
Then $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cong\operatorname{Sym}(X)$. Since $G=\operatorname{FSym}(X)$ is a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$, $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ acts on $G$ by conjugation, giving a group homomorphism $\operatorname{Sym}(X)\to\operatorname{Aut}(G)$. It's not too hard to show that this homomorphism is injective (i.e., no nontrivial permutation of $X$ commutes with every finitary permutation), but in fact it is also surjective, and is therefore an isomorphism.
I think that this is quite a well-known fact, but it took a while for me to find a reference. A more general result is proved in Theorem 11.4.8 (5) of
Scott, W. R., Group theory, Englewood Cliffs, N. J.: Prentice-Hall, Inc. 479 p. (1964). ZBL0126.04504.
It is also a consequence of Theorem 8.2A in
Dixon, John D.; Mortimer, Brian, Permutation groups, Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 163. New York, NY: Springer-Verlag. xii, 346 p. (1996). ZBL0951.20001.
This answers the question, since $X$ and $G$ have the same cardinality, and so
$$\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cong\operatorname{Sym}(X)\cong
\operatorname{Sym}(G).$$
